# Swashbuckle/Swagger not picking up routes from config

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle (a .NET wrapper around swagger).

When I am generating my swagger documentation, it generates the URIs in the documentation from the controller names/parameters instead of the defined routes as they are defined in config at application startup.

So I have a controller:

```
namespace Pat.PostingService.Api.Version1
{
    public class DeliveryStatusController : ApiController
    {
         [ResponseType(typeof(DeliveryStatusDto))]
         public dynamic Get(string deliveryType, Guid? orderId = null)
         {
             ...
         }
    }
{
```

and in the RouteConfig.cs file, I redefine the route:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ...

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DeliveryStatusService",
         routeTemplate: "SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}",
         defaults: new {
             controller = "DeliveryStatus",
             orderId = RouteParameter.Optional
         }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Default",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When calling the API, I now cannot use the `/DeliveryStatus` endpoint, I must use the `/SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus` endpoint.

HOWEVER, the Swagger documentation states that the endpoint is `/DeliveryStatus`.

Together with my colleagues, we believe that `_apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions` (from System.Web.Http.Description.IApiExplorer used by SwaggerGenerator.cs in Swashbuckle.Core) is returning us the incorrect routes, although we may be wrong.

What have we missed? Is there something that we can use to ensure Swagger uses the routes used in config and not the default routes?

---

edit:

We are also using SDammann for versioning (imagine a second RouteConfig.cs file in a version2 folder), which does not support [AttributeRouting], hence our need for the route to be picked up from the startup route config.

---

edit 2:

Putting `action = "Get"` into the defaults for the routes doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: This is weird, I just tested your code, and I get a perfect result...
It shows me the endpoint as /SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}.
Try creating an ISchemaFilter and check the ApiDescription - if you are willing you could change the path here, although that would require alot of static code and lots of operationIds (wouldn't be a problem if that is your only endpoint though)

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you register/map your routes plays a big part in the route table as first match wins. Your example shows how you register the route in question but not the position in which it is registered in relation to your other routes.

For example, if you register your default route before the route in question

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ...

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Default",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DeliveryStatusService",
         routeTemplate: "SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}",
         defaults: new {
             controller = "DeliveryStatus",
             orderId = RouteParameter.Optional
         }
    );
}
```

... then a `GET /DeliveryStatus` will match by convention to

```
public dynamic Get(string deliveryType, Guid? orderId = null) { ... }
```

especially if `id` placeholder is optional.

So check to make sure you have the correct order of your route mappings. The default route is usually mapped last as the fallback route.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ...

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DeliveryStatusService",
         routeTemplate: "SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}",
         defaults: new {
             controller = "DeliveryStatus",
             orderId = RouteParameter.Optional
         }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Default",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you are not adverse to using [attribute routing in web api 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), you could instead do...

```
namespace Pat.PostingService.Api.Version1
{
    [RoutePrefix("SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus")]
    public class DeliveryStatusController : ApiController
    {
         //GET SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}
         [HttpGet]
         [Route("{deliveryType}/{orderId?}")]
         [ResponseType(typeof(DeliveryStatusDto))]
         public dynamic Get(string deliveryType, Guid? orderId = null) { ... }
    }
}
```

and in the RouteConfig.cs file, configure attribute route:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    ...

}
```

again order of mapping is important and that is why normally it is configured before other mappings.

### UPDATE:

Try the following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DeliveryStatusService",
     routeTemplate: "SpecialDeliveryServiceStatus/{deliveryType}/{orderId}",
     defaults: new {
         controller = "DeliveryStatus",
         action = "Get"
         orderId = RouteParameter.Optional
     }
);
```

and in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(DeliveryStatusDto))]
public dynamic Get(string deliveryType, Guid? orderId = null) { ... }
```

to make sure there are no guesses by the route table as to which route the action is mapped.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi for this answer - I probably should have put it there, but we DO have the most general route at the bottom (and I have tried rearranging just to check).

Comment: Similarly, we have tried attribute based routing, but we are using SDammann for versioning and it doesn't support attribute based routing, hence our need for Swashbuckle to support startup route config.

Comment: You should update the question with these details so that others can better understand the full picture.

Comment: Did you try manually setting the `action="Get"` in the defaults of the route mapping. ie `defaults: new {
             controller = "DeliveryStatus",
             action = "Get",
             orderId = RouteParameter.Optional
         }`. as well as the `HttpGet` attribute so as to make sure there are no guesses as to which route the action belongs to?

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't fix the issue :(